# Updating multiple cloned contracts

Tags: solidity, contract-development, factory, clone

A quick question: if a contract factory has generated quite a bunch of contracts by cloning, and one parameter is desired to be updated across all such cloned contracts, what is the best approach for achieving that? Suppose a setter is available for all such contracts. And a good measure would be low gas costs, and easy to implement and quick in execution.

One more constraint to add: the generated contracts do not belong to me, or any known individual. They are in the wild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with existing contracts, there's not much you can do other than send these updates in batches to save on the transaction fee overhead.

However, if you are deploying new proxy contracts from scratch, then you can use a single separate contract to hold the settings you wish to update. The proxy contracts will look up their settings from this contract which will allow updating the settings on all contracts with a single write.

For example:

```js
contract Settings(){
  uint256 public fooValue = 1;

  function setFooValue(uint256 x){
    fooValue = x;
  }
}

contract MyContract(){
  settings Settings = Settings(0x1234...)
  
  function doSomething() public {
    uint256 foo = settings.fooValue()
  }
}
```

By calling `settings.setFooValue(19)`, I can change all deployed contracts at cost of only around 25,000 gas, even if there are tens of thousands of deployed contracts.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel. This is a good illustration. Is there anyway of telling `MyContract` that `fooValue` has changed in the `Settings` contract? If `foo` is an important contract-wide setting parameter, it has be updated outside the scope of one function. Since the owner of `MyContract` does not have the incentive to update a setting parameter or may not even be informed about it, a more robust and reliable approach is desired.

Comment: To add one thought, is it possible to use oracle to force all such cloned smart contracts to update a state viable?

Comment: You don't have to tell it that the value updated because every time it uses the value it goes and fetches it from the `Settings` contract, which means it will always be using the most up to date value.

Comment: Somehow I was trying to avoid reading from another contract even though it is free, maybe it can be not free?